# ics file not parsing with R calendar package

Tags: r, icalendar

Looking for advice about whether the problem I have run into is related to the structure of the ics file I am trying to import or possibly a problem with the `calendar` package, as I can't quite work out what is wrong.

I have a work roster which I can access via a weblink from the roster system (AllocateMe). This downloads an ics file if you put it into a web browser or imports the calendar into which ever calendar program you want, I've tried Outlook and MacOS calendar with no issues; works as expected.

However, when I try to parse the following ics file with `calendar::ic_read()`:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:healthroster
X-WR-CALNAME:R
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:45768392
DTSTAMP:20230405T230000Z
DTSTART:20230406T110000Z
DTEND:20230406T190000Z
LOCATION:Admitting
DESCRIPTION:Rest Time : 00:00\n
SUMMARY:Late shift
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:46794060
DTSTAMP:20230410T230000Z
DTSTART:20230411T070000Z
DTEND:20230411T110000Z
LOCATION:Admitting
DESCRIPTION:Rest Time : 00:00\n
SUMMARY:Early shift
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I get the following message:

```
Error in if (!is.na(x) & !x == "NA" & !grepl("^\\d{8}T\\d{6}Z?$", x)) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

I have passed this through the debugger sequentially. It looks like `ic_read()` reads in everyline of the file to a character vector. It uses the function `ical()` to try to convert this to an ical class object.

Passing the vector and its output sequentially into the functions used, `ical()` fails when using `ic_dataframe()` and ultimately `ic_dataframe()` fails when trying to apply `ic_datetime()` to the date columns of the dataframe.

`ic_datetime()` looks like this:

```
function (x) 
{
  if (!is.na(x) & !x == "NA" & !grepl("^\\d{8}T\\d{6}Z?$", 
    x)) {
    warning("Non-standard time string: should be in this format: 20180809T160000Z")
    x = ""
  }
  plain <- gsub("[TZtz]", "", x)
  datetime <- as.POSIXct(plain, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
  datetime
}
```

If you shorten the above ics file to just one event it works ok:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:healthroster
X-WR-CALNAME:R
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:45768392
DTSTAMP:20230405T230000Z
DTSTART:20230406T110000Z
DTEND:20230406T190000Z
LOCATION:Admitting
DESCRIPTION:Rest Time : 00:00\n
SUMMARY:Late shift
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The very bizarre thing is if I import an ics created with MacOS calendar with multiple events, it parses it seemingly without an issue other than it fails to convert the date columns to datetime, leaving them as character.

Any thoughts would be welcome, including if I should contact the developer.

Comment: It looks like other people are experiencing the same issue based on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/ATFutures/calendar/issues/44. There isn't currently a solution listed there as there's no reproducible example in the existing GitHub issue. You may want to add your example there.

Comment: thanks for this. I couldn't find a GitHub repo link for this package when I looked on CRAN. I will post there and see what the developer thinks.

Comment: It can be tricky sometimes. Two things you can try when you're looking for the "real" source repo for a package: (1) go to `github.com/cran/calendar` and look around, sometimes something in the docs or source (that may not be in the package itself?) can give you a hint; in this case, it does, because (2) in the package [`README`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/calendar/readme/README.html) (link is to CRAN's version of that file), it says at the top: _"INSTALLATION `devtools::install_github("ATFutures/calendar")`"_, which means you can go to github.com/ATFutures/calendar to find it.